# Optimizing a view including a union in Mysql before version 8.0

Tags: mysql, view, union

I have a view that combines the contents of two tables like this

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
(SELECT some_key, x FROM a)
UNION ALL
(SELECT some_key, x FROM b)
```

I want to query the view like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE some_key = '123'
```

This is possible but it's very slow since the complete view seems to be materialized before applying the filter/condition. In theory the condition can be pushed down to both the selects the union is made of  but it's not happening. It appears this feature [is available in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-condition-pushdown-optimization.html)

How can I work around this in earlier versions of MySQL? I thought about left joining both tables to another table with the same key to trick MySQL into applying the `where` condition first but I didn't succeed. I assume it would even be faster when I would run over the matching keys and generate the union separately only for the matching records in both tables. I thought about doing this with a kind of subquery within a select on the third table (containing only the keys) but i don't know how I could union the results again.

Comment: "...it's very slow since the complete view seems to be materialized before..." -- Yes, that's most likely true. For a query to be performant you need to filter out rows as soon as possible. In this case, it's not the view that's preventing that, but the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I don't know of a solution to the problem you describe in MySQL 5.x. You should upgrade anyway, because MySQL 5.7 will be past its end-of-life in about 18 months from now.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT of the desired query.

Comment: Alas, MySQL's VIEWs are mostly syntactic sugar; they sometimes get in the way of Optimization.

Comment: Would you like to discuss whether those two tables can be combined?  Or build a 3rd table with the common info?

Comment: @RickJames The goal is in fact to combine the information in both tables. However, for the time being the new data should be consumed as a view in order to avoid redundancy until the data has been migrated to a new materialized table.

Comment: @lex82 - With some extra effort, you could write a Stored Procedure that dynamically builds the test into each Select, thereby (hopefully) making it run much faster.